# How to create array with requested length?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have some array

ex:

```
val arr1: Array <String> = arrayOf("one", "two", "tree")
```

length of array is unknown (one, two, tree for example only).

How to create one more array with same length but different type?

ex:

```
val arr2: = Array <Boolean) = arrayOf(false, false, false) //must be same quantity of items as in arr1
```

Comment: You should use a BooleanArray, not an Array<Boolean>. The documentation is your friend: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean-array/index.html

Comment: Note that if the `String` is closely connected to the corresponding `Boolean`, then you might consider putting both of them into an object, such as a `data class`, and having a single array of those.  (Parallel arrays can be a ‘code smell’.)

Comment: I need two arrays for creating of Dialog with checkBoxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val arr2 = Array(arr1.size) { false }
```

This will create an array of the same size as `arr1`, with all values being set to `false`.

Changing the value inside the `{ }` will change the type of array. For more information on Kotlin arrays, [see the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array()` constructor. It takes the size and a function.

Reference: [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays)